# Referring to object names within its Class itself

Tags: python, oop

My code:

```
  import math
  class Cal(object):

        def __init__(self,precision):
            self.precision=precision

        def roundTo(self):
           if(obj1):
               return (round(math.pi,self.precision))
           elif(obj2):
               return (round(math.e,self.precision))

    precision=int(raw_input("enter number:"))
    obj1=Cal(precision)
    answer1=obj1.roundTo()
    print answer1
    obj2=Cal(precision)
    answer2=obj2.roundTo()
    print answer2
```

My problem here is, I want the same method to return two different things on both the objects depending upon the object that is referenced.
Is there a way to do this:

```
def fun_name(self):
    if(obj1):
       #return
    elif(obj2): 
       #return
```

I know the simpler way would be to create two different functions and assign each of them to individual objects. But is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: So you want the code for the class to depend on which instance it's being called on? That seems very unwise. As they both have the same interface (`precision` on instantiation, `roundTo` method) why not make two subclasses, then `obj1 = PiCal(precision)` and `obj2 = ECal(precision)`. Or make the base number (`math.pi` and `math.e`) another argument provided on instantiation (`obj1 = (math.pi, precision)`, etc.).

Comment: I exactly wanted this: "want the code for the class to depend on which instance it's being called on" ,but you are right it is not wise doing it that way.

Comment: yeah they belong to same interface(the same class). Its needless.!

Comment: In fact, if this is your whole example, the class itself is pointless. Just call `round` twice!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to identify objects by name looks like bad design, because an object does not know its own name.  Look why it is impossible:

```
# let's have two objects with two names
obj1 = Cal()
obj2 = Cal()

# you can swap names
obj1, obj2 = obj2, obj1

# you can have two equally valid names for the same object
obj3 = obj1

# you can reuse a name for something else
obj2saved = obj2
obj2 = None

# and you can have objects without a name
obj_set = { Cal(), Cal() }
```